# Node Js - Session management

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

I have a simple application, which will login a user and based on his role will let him use a specific API (say normal/admin..view/update respectively). I am using MYSQL to Authenticate users and connection pool to manage many connections to app.

This is how i am managing session,

```
app.use(expressSession({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'mysecret',
  duration: 15 * 60 * 1000,
}));
```

At login,

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    Authenticate(req.body.username,req.body.password,function(err,fname,user){
        if(!err) {
                req.session.name=user;
                res.send("Welcome " + fname);
            }
        else{
                res.send("There seems to be an issue with the username/password combination that you entered");         
            }
    });
});
```

and whenever i want to access any specific API,i will check for this session name.

```
app.post('/updateInfo',function(req,res){
    if(req.session.name){
 // My logic - i ll return the role by searching in db using this req.session.name, if admin will allow him.
}
});
```

I will destroy the session in logout.

I have two questions since i don't understand the mechanism of the session in node js.

1. Now suppose i login as admin user and after authentication export
   the cookie (say using edit this cookie chrome extension) and logout.
   Then login as normal user and import the cookie(admin cookie), will
   there be any breach (because now the session will contain admin username)?
2. Suppose if i want to avoid multiple
       connections for a same user (user using different browser/mobile     to login), can i just add this piece of code?

   ```
   if(req.session.name == req.body.username)
   {
   req.session.destroy();
   }
   ```

and then continue to authenticate? What are the drawbacks here? Why will it work or not work?

I really would love to make this stateless(don't want to persist state/session in db) because i want performance. Can i do something that is stateless and still works even when there are 100s of concurrent users?

Comment: Regarding first question, i still don't know. I tried with Edit this cookie in chrome but somehow the cookie is import is working on other sites but not in mine.

Comment: Regarding second, it will not work as each request will have its own session and will not go into the 'if' block. We need to have session state if we are going to have multiple session.